# How to use forward declarations for a template class in a shared pointer (in C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, shared-ptr

I have a base class `Base` defined in **Base.h**:

```
class Base
{ /* ... */ };
```

And a class template `Child` that derives from `Base`, defined in **Child.h**:

```
#include "Base.h"

template <class T>
class Child : public Base
{ /* ... */ };
```

Now I want to create some factory methods within the `Base` class, which should return a `std::shared_ptr` to the `Child` class. To avoid circular dependencies I tried to use a forward declaration instead. So **Base.h** now looks like this:

```
class Child; // new forward declaration

class Base
{
    /* ... */

    // new factory method
    static std::shared_ptr<Base> CreateChildInt(int i = 0)
    {
        return std::make_shared<Child<int>>(i);
    }
};
```

However, the definition of `CreateChildInt()` leads to the following compiler error:

*"error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate template-argument-list, found '<'"*

So is this even possible what I am trying to achieve?
If not, are there any workarounds / best practices for this approach?

**EDIT**:
The reason for why I want to put the factory method into the `Base` class instead of `Child` is the following. When I put the factory into `Child` I would need to call the factory method like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = Child<int>::CreateChildInt(3);
```

However, I would like to omit the template type `<int>` in this call, thus:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = Base::CreateChildInt(3);
```

Comment: You need `template <typename> class Child;`.

Comment: Why is this factory function part of `Base`? Normally OO base classes aren't supposed to be aware of their children.

Comment: @Matthias I wouldn't put it in either class. It's `static` anyway; why not leave it outside?

Comment: Ohh dear! I have worked too long with Java, so that I have not even thought about the idea to create a normal function outside a class. That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you declared a class, but `Child` that you define is actually a template. The correct way to declare a class template is:

```
template <class T>
class Child;
```

However, a correct forward declaration alone won't help you. The implementation of `CreateChildInt::CreateChildInt` must know the full definition of `Child` because it creates an instance of it. You can't define `Child` before `Base` either, because inheritance also depends on the full definition, so you'd end up with a cicrular dependency.

Solution: Forward declare `Child`, then define `Base` but don't define `Base::CreateChildInt` inline, then define `Child` and finally define `Base::CreateChildInt`.

---

PS. I find it dubious from OOP perspective that the implementation of the base class member function depends on the child class. I recommend that you consider re-designing your approach.

Comment: I have updated my original question to better explain what I am trying to achieve, and why I want to put the factory method into the `Base` class.

Comment: @Matthias you have a strong argument against putting the factory function into the child class, but do you have any argument for putting the factory function into the base class instead of outside?

Comment: You're right, coming from Java I have not thought about the idea of putting the function outside a class :)